# BeanCreationException and NoClassDefFoundError : What am I missing in here?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, compiler-errors

I have following file upload code:

```
package net.viralpatel.contact.controller;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.ObjectError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import net.viralpatel.contact.dao.FileUpload;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/fileupload")
public class FileUploadController {

    public FileUploadController() {
        System.out.println("FileUploadController is Started");
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String doGet(Model model) {
        System.out.println("Inside doGet method of FileUploadController");
        model.addAttribute(new FileUpload());
        return "fileUpload";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String upload(FileUpload fileUpload, BindingResult result) {
System.out.println("Inside upload method of FileUploadController");
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            for (ObjectError error : result.getAllErrors()) {
                log.error("Error binding result. Code: {}, Message: {}",
                        error.getCode(), error.getDefaultMessage());
            }
            return "fileUpload";
        }

        log.debug("fileUpload: {}", fileUpload);
        log.debug("File Uploaded with name {} and size: {}",
                fileUpload.getName(), fileUpload.getFileData().getSize());
        return "fileUpload";
    }
}
```

My web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Spring3-Hibernate</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>list.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <!-- Added for File Upload -->
<!--     <init-param> -->
<!--            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> -->
<!--            <param-value> -->
<!--                /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml -->
<!--            </param-value> -->
<!--    </init-param> -->
    <!-- Added for FileUpload -->
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My spring-servlet.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.viralpatel.contact" />

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<!--    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" -->
<!--        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" -->
<!--        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" /> -->

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ContactManager" p:username="root" p:password="12345" />


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

<!-- FileUpload -->
<!-- Configure the multipart resolver -->
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>
    </bean>
<!-- For FileUpload -->

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

When I try to run the application the am getting:

**Updated - stacktrace**

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet spring threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:403)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:301)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:162)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:140)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

**ends**
    root cause

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileUploadController' defined in file [C:\Software\Server\Tomcat v7\apache-tomcat-7.0.16\webapps\MavenWeb-0.0.1\WEB-INF\classes\net\viralpatel\contact\controller\FileUploadController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.viralpatel.contact.controller.FileUploadController
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:965)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:403)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:301)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:162)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:140)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.viralpatel.contact.controller.FileUploadController
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:74)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:958)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:403)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:301)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:162)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:140)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I checked classpath and I have it set properly then why not FileUploadController is working? Any suggestions?

> Update: .classpath file for my project

```
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java" output="target/test-classes" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/resources" output="target/test-classes" excluding="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources" excluding="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javax/servlet/jstl/1.1.2/jstl-1.1.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javax/transaction/jta/1.1/jta-1.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javax/persistence/persistence-api/1.0/persistence-api-1.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/antlr/antlr/2.7.6/antlr-2.7.6.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/asm/asm/1.5.3/asm-1.5.3.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/asm/asm-attrs/1.5.3/asm-attrs-1.5.3.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/cglib/cglib/2.1_3/cglib-2.1_3.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.1/commons-collections-3.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.2.2/commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0.4/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/commons-pool/commons-pool/1.4/commons-pool-1.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/net/sf/ehcache/ehcache/1.2.3/ehcache-1.2.3.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/hibernate/ejb3-persistence/1.0.1.GA/ejb3-persistence-1.0.1.GA.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/hibernate/hibernate/3.2.6.ga/hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/hibernate/hibernate-annotations/3.3.1.GA/hibernate-annotations-3.3.1.GA.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/hibernate/hibernate-commons-annotations/3.0.0.ga/hibernate-commons-annotations-3.0.0.ga.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.3.1.GA/hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/3.3.2.GA/hibernate-entitymanager-3.3.2.GA.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javassist/javassist/3.4.GA/javassist-3.4.GA.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.17/mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.5.2/slf4j-api-1.5.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.1/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-aop/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-asm/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-context/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-context-support/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-context-support-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-core/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-expression/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-orm/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-tx/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-tx-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-web/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/taglibs/standard/1.1.2/standard-1.1.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
</classpath>
```

**Update**

Just wanted to add an update on this question - finally, i was able to get FileUpload working but I had to start fresh, i created FileUploadController again and did all wiring again and now it seems to be working fine. Still, I am not able to figure out what was the issue of earlier errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the tag (mvc:annotation-driven) in your spring context file. Please add that to your context file that should resolve the problem.

Comment: `<context:annotation-config />` i have this tag and i thought it would suffice? correct me if my understanding is wrong

Comment: I think mvc:annotation-driven is what identifies @controller tag.

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977973/whats-the-difference-between-mvcannotation-driven-and-contextannotation-c

Comment: sorry, looks like u don't mvc tag.

Comment: and what was your reasoning behind that ?

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileUploadController' defined in file [C:\Software\Server\Tomcat v7\apache-tomcat-7.0.16\webapps\MavenWeb-0.0.1\classes\net\viralpatel\contact\controller\FileUploadController.class]:NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.viralpatel.contact.controller.FileUploadController

Comment: i have question regarding how you are running the app. If I am reading  the stack trace correctly looks like you created a war and deployed it to tomcat server. I also want to know if it is possible for you to run tomcat and point it to local workspace?

Comment: yes you are correct, i am creating war and putting it in webapp folder of tomcat server and then trying to re-start the server and see if it is working fine.

Comment: do you run the same server apache-tomcat-7.0.16 from eclipse workspace?, If you do can you go to the workspace directory on your machine workspacedir\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp\wtpwebapps, If you find MavenWeb-0.0.1 there delete that and restart the tomcat

Comment: i am not using tomcat from eclipse but rather i just going to commandline and starting and shutting it down and deploying webapp from Manager-gui interface

Comment: I think I am out of ideas, I just want to you look one last detail, go to the MavenWeb-0.0.1\classes, locate the class FileUploadController, the directory structure of the class should be classes\net\viralpatel\contact\controller\FileUploadController.class, If it is not the case then JVM won't be able to load the class

Comment: /MavenWeb/target/MavenWeb-0.0.1/WEB-INF/classes/net/viralpatel/contact/controller/FileUploadController.class is the path

Answer (score 0):

If CLASSPATH means environment variable to you, then that's your problem.

You need to have all your dependency JARs in your app's WEB-INF/lib directory OR in the /lib directory for your app server.  (Preferrably the WEB-INF/lib.)

Delete your CLASSPATH environment variable; it's not necessary, and it's done nothing but misled you in this case.

Comment: I do understand from your previous comments to other questions that CLASSPATH is not enviornment variable and trust me I know that but here the issue is that I do have all required jar and more over FileUploadController is an individual controller not packed in any jar and I do see it's .class in target folder

Comment: i have updated question with details about `.classpath` file which list all the dependent jar

Comment: what else would you try to look out for in such scenarios ?

Comment: the .classpath file in your project - which is an Eclipse IDE metadata file - is *not* related to the classpath used by the servlet container when you run your app. Your classes need to be in `WEB-INF/classes` or a jar in `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: @matt b - ok, i checked `target/MavenWeb-0.0.1/WEB-INF/classes/net/test/contact/controller/FileUploadController.class`, so i have FileUploadController.class in there but still from error messages it says that NoClassDefFoundError, any thoughts as to why am getting that error message even when i have required class in classpath?

Comment: Looks like the full classname in the stacktrace (`net.viralpatel.contact.controller.FileUploadController`) is not the same as what is in your output folder.

Comment: @matt b - But it should be pointing to correct location right ?

Comment: It seems to me that Maven and Eclipse are doing you no good here.  I would recommend that you stop depending on both of them and simply do it properly.