# Spring MVC example not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm in trouble and would like your help. I'm a beginner in Spring MVC (and Spring at all). I have followed the http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/ but it isn't working on. I added a welcome file **(index.jsp)**. When i enter **(http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC)** all right. But when i add the controller pattern **(http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/welcome)**, it doesn't work (HTTP Status 404). Here my configs:

**web.xml**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.common.controller" />
    <bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

and my folder structure is:

```
-> src
   -> main
      -> java
         -> com
            -> mkyong
               -> common
                  -> controller
                     -> HelloController.java
      -> resources
      -> webapp
         -> index.jsp
         -> WEB-INF
            -> mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
            -> web.xml
            -> pages
               -> hello.jsp
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Can I recommend turning the log level to DEBUG and seeing what Spring prints out - if Spring DispatcherServlet gets the request then you will see a lot of information in the logs that should clearly indicate what is going wrong.

Comment: Try placing this content in a log4j.properties file in the classpath - 

log4j.rootLogger=trace, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

Comment: When i enter **http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC** he says:
    **WARN: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'**.

Comment: Very good, now it is little more clear - So your context is deployed at root context (`/`) not `/SpringMVC`, try the first answer and see what message you get http://localhost:8080/welcome

Answer (score 1):

404 means that the requested resource cannot be found. Make sure your controller is annotated with:

```
@Controller and @RequestMapping("/welcome")
```

From the link:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("message", "Spring 3 MVC Hello World");
        return "hello";

    }

}
```

Comment: The class **HelloController** is marked with **@Controller, RequestMapping** as it must be.

Answer (score 0):

You have your servlet mapped to '/', and the controller you want to hit is accepting requests for '/welcome'

The request you need to make should be (**http://localhost:8080/welcome**).  I don't know why he has that extra 'SpringMVC' in his example.

Also, add `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` to your `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` to make sure it's using annotations on your controller(s).  And add the mvc XML namespace also.  My namespaces look like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
```

I would suggest getting rid of that welcome file until you have your controller working correctly to keep things simple

Comment: Making such request **http://localhost:8080/welcome** still returns HTTP Status 404. I don't know what is happening.

Comment: What version of spring are you using?

Comment: **3.0.5.RELEASE** according to the **pom.xml**.

Comment: @mnatan.brito edited answer.  try adding mvc annotation stuff

Comment: Are you talking about **@Controller, @RequestMapping**?

Comment: Yeah.  I have a very similar project and have the <mvc:annotation-driven/> tag in my servlet config.  When I remove it, I get 404s.  According to this answer, there are two ways of getting annotations to work:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3978283/78716

Answer (score 0):

You must have a Controller mapped to "/".

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class StartController {

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {

    model.addAttribute("message", "Spring 3 MVC Hello World");
    return "hello";

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include this library on your view to enable `${}`

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

This will solve your problem.