# Spring web MVC intrigation with JAX WS

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jax-ws

Hi All I'm Integrating Spring web mvc into Jax-ws The below are my code.
The web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/spring/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jaxws-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jaxws-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml file is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core  http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd
    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.softid" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<wss:binding url="/hello">
    <wss:service>
        <ws:service bean="#helloWs" />
    </wss:service>
</wss:binding>
```

My Pom.xml file is below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mkyong.common</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringMVC</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>SpringMVC Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Library from java.net, integrate Spring with JAX-WS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xbean</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream.buffer</groupId>
                <artifactId>streambuffer</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.staxex</groupId>
                <artifactId>stax-ex</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>SpringMVC</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now the problem is, when i'm add spring jax-ws stuff then the spring dispatcher servelt is not working. Like if I hit a URL `http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/spring/welcome` it's giving 404 error. In console it's showing

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/spring/welcome] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'.
```

If I remove the jax-ws stuff then it's working fine. Can any one please tell me what wrong i'm doing.

EDIT:

My Controller class for welcome is

```
package com.softid.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Spring 3 MVC Hello World");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: If you remove the JAX-WS stuff does your MVC code work as-is?   I don't see anything that immediately stands out as something in your configuration that is wrong. Are you using JAX-WS RI to deploy your web service?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Tomcat to deploy my application

Answer (score 0):

you should use "SpringMVC/spring/hello" instead of "SpringMVC/spring/welcome". because you mentioned wsdl name as "hello"

Comment: Spring ws stuff is working fine that is SpringMVC/spring/hello is working but the MVC stuff that is SpringMVC/spring/welcome is not working I have controller class with welcome as request mapping annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing one important tag in your dispatcher xml file.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
&
<context:annotation-config>
```

These Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model.
Add those at the start of the xml after xmlns entries.
This should work.
Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977973/whats-the-difference-between-mvcannotation-driven-and-contextannotation) for your reference.