# Spring MVC: difference between <context:component-scan> and <annotation-driven /> tags?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

Some days ago I began to study this Spring Hello World Tutorial: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-create-hello-world-application-spring-3-mvc/

In this tutorial Spring DispatcherServlet is configured using the *spring-servlet.xml* file, this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="net.viralpatel.spring3.controller" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

In this file I am using the **context:component-scan** tag to say that Spring have to scan my file searching the annotation, so for example, when the controller class finds that a method is annotated by **@RequestMapping("/hello")** annotation knows that this method handles the HTTP Request toward the URL ending with "/hello". This is simple...

Now my doubt is related to the Spring MVC template project that I could automatically build in STS\Eclipse.

When I create a new Spring MVC project in STS I have that my *DispatcherServlet* is configured by a file named **servlet-context.xml** that contains some configuration similar to the previous example file.

In this file, I still have  the component scan tag:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.maventestwebapp" />
```

but I have also another tag (that look like have similar task), this one:

```
<annotation-driven />
```

What is the difference between these two tags?
An other "strange" thing is that the previous example (that don't use the annotation-driven tag) is very similar to the project create by STS using the Spring MVC Template project but if I delete the annotation-driven tag from its configuration file the project don't run and give me the following error: **HTTP Status 404 -**

And in the stacktrace I have:

**WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/maventestwebapp/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'**

But why? The previous example works well without annotation-driven tag, and this controller class is very similar. In fact, there is only one method that handles HTTP request toward "/" path

This is the code of my controller class:

```
package com.mycompany.maventestwebapp;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
*/
@Controller
public class HomeController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

/**
 * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

    model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

    return "home";
}
```

Can someone help me to understand this thing?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977973/whats-the-difference-between-mvcannotation-driven-and-contextannotation. This answer is excellent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977973/whats-the-difference-between-mvcannotation-driven-and-contextannotation

Comment: interesting, but does not entirely meet my doubts

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`<mvc:annotation-driven />` means that you can define spring beans dependencies without actually having to specify a bunch of  elements in XML or implement an interface or extend a base class. For example `@Repository` to tell spring that a class is a Dao without having to extend `JpaDaoSupport` or some other subclass of DaoSupport. Similarly `@Controller` tells spring that the class specified contains methods that will handle Http requests without you having to implement the Controller interface or extend a subclass that implements the controller.

When spring starts up it reads its XML configuration file and looks for `<bean` elements within it if it sees something like `<bean class="com.example.Foo" />` and  Foo was marked up with `@Controller` it knows that the class is a controller and treats it as such. By default, Spring assumes that all the classes it should manage are explicitly defined in the beans.XML file.

Component scanning with `<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.maventestwebapp" />` is telling spring that it should search the classpath for all the classes under com.mycompany.maventestweapp and look at each class to see if it has a `@Controller`, or `@Repository`, or `@Service`, or `@Component` and if it does then Spring will register the class with the bean factory as if you had typed `<bean class="..." />` in the XML configuration files.

In a typical spring MVC app you will find that there are two spring configuration files, a file that configures the application context usually started with the Spring context listener.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And a Spring MVC configuration file usually started with the Spring dispatcher servlet. For example.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Spring has support for hierarchical bean factories, so in the case of the Spring MVC, the dispatcher servlet context is a child of the main application context. If the servlet context was asked for a bean called "abc" it will look in the servlet context first, if it does not find it there it will look in the parent context, which is the application context.

Common beans such as data sources, JPA configuration, business services are defined in the application context while MVC specific configuration goes not the configuration file associated with the servlet.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, this is quite clear but I don't understand why the other web site example don't use annotation-driven tag and the STS example need it...

Comment: Spring has not always had annotations and and component scanning so you are likely to see all sorts of examples online showing all sorts of different techniques and combinations.

Comment: Is <mvc:annotation-driven /> tag necessary still ? I just tested one Spring 3.0 demo application without <mvc:annotation-driven /> only <context:component-Scan....> tag and my application works fine!!!! Infact- almost none of tutorials these days put <mvc:annotation-driven /> in there spring-servlet.xml

Answer (score 30):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="" />
```

tells Spring to scan those packages for Annotations.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
```

registers a RequestMappingHanderMapping, a RequestMappingHandlerAdapter, and an ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver to support the annotated controller methods like @RequestMapping, @ExceptionHandler, etc. that come with MVC.

This also enables a ConversionService that supports Annotation driven formatting of outputs as well as Annotation driven validation for inputs. It also enables support for @ResponseBody which you can use to return JSON data.

You can accomplish the same things using Java-based Configuration using @ComponentScan(basePackages={"...", "..."}  and @EnableWebMvc in a @Configuration class.

Check out the 3.1 documentation to learn more.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config

Answer (score 12):

Annotation-driven indicates to Spring that it should scan for annotated beans, and to not just rely on XML bean configuration.  Component-scan indicates where to look for those beans.

Here's some doc: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable