# mvc:annotation-driven does not work in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I have the `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` annotation which errors out. The error I get is :
The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:annotation-driven'.

When I used the beans

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
```

it works fine. How is that possible

My complete Spring context XML file is :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/
         xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-2.5.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that there is no `mvc:annotation-driven` annotation in Spring 2.5, I think it was [introduced in Spring 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977973/whats-the-difference-between-mvcannotation-driven-and-contextannotation). Consider using the current version of Spring.

I could not find the actual `http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-2.5.xsd` I'm not sure that it even existed.

Comment: +1. The [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config) clearly says it (quote, emphasis mine): "**Spring 3 introduces a mvc** XML configuration namespace ...".

Answer (score -1):

Missign dependcy spring-webmvc, show your pom