# How can I add Spring Boot into an existing project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to Spring and Java in general. I am working on a REST API and want to use Spring. I have read the Spring docs on [getting started with Spring](https://spring.io/quickstart) but most of them only talk about how to start a Spring project from scratch. I already have an existing Maven project and want to add Spring to that. Can anyone help with that?

I'm using IntelliJ CE 2020.3 if that helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add spring boot to existing project without changing the main(args\[\]) method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39816394/add-spring-boot-to-existing-project-without-changing-the-mainargs-method)

Answer (score 4):

Using Spring actually impacts the organisation of your code, and Spring boot even more.
I don't know the size of your existing project, but my first idea would be to build a new application structure using spring boot, then copy the "flesh" of your existing code into this structure, step by step.

Using only chosen bits of Spring / Spring boot is difficult, and certainly dangerous (for mental health) with no experience.

hth

Comment: "certainly dangerous for mental health": thanks for the giggle!  Also, my (to date, somewhat limited) experience of Spring Boot suggests that this is indeed the best approach.

Comment: Using spring nor spring boot impacts the organisation of your code. It might require some additional setup to get your current structure working but you dn't need to restructure things.

Comment: Makes sense, I guess I'll just build a new Spring Boot project within the existing package hierarchy and then `@Service` my existing class.