# @RequestBody not working - HTTP Status 415

Tags: angularjs, spring, http, spring-restcontroller, http-status-code-415

I have a problem. I try so send http post to my controller with angularjs.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/books/manage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void manageBooks(@RequestBody final BooksDTO dto)
        throws SystemException, IOException {
    System.out.println("DTO WAS SEND!");
    }
}
```

Here Angularjs

```
$http.post($scope.BooksUrl, {
                        'title':Title,
                        'booksUrl':Url,
                        'number':Number
                }).error(function (response) {
                    // error message
                }).then(function(){
                    // success message
                });
```

The header is

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:72
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

But It catchs "HTTP - 415 status. The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method." How I can resolve it?

Responce headers

```
Content-Length:1048
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 21 Oct 2015 06:00:39 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection:1
```

pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>portal-service</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>util-bridges</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>util-taglib</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>util-java</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--Spring dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.books.**"/>
<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

Answer (score 1):

try using the below code in your controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/books/manage", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes="application/json")
```

Answer (score 1):

This could also be due to missing message converter. Try to register one (Jackson in your case). The java object needs to be converted to JSON, this is done by JSON message converter. If if use @EnableWebMVC or mvc:annotation-driven tag (in case of xml config) and jackson is added to your classpath then MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter is implicitly added. See if your pom has Jackson dependency else add following:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you describe what you mean?

Comment: Aww, you are right, I forgot to add maven depency to jackson data bind. I will try and answer you later

Comment: adding jackson-databind to pom.xml didn't help too

Comment: Can you paste your configuration and pom here? that might help.

Comment: I forgot to add that I'm using Liferay. I try to delegate servlet for rest service

Comment: added pom and configuration

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. The problem was in servlet xml:

```
<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

should be replaced with

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

I don't know what's the difference, but it works (Can someone explain?)
Thank you all for answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know what's the difference, but it works (Can someone explain?) Thank you all for answer.

tx:annotation-driven - used to enable transaction annotations like @Transactional

mvc:annotation-driven - used to enable Spring MVC annotations like @Controller

Here some similar question [What's the difference between <mvc:annotation-driven /> and <context:annotation-config /> in servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977973/whats-the-difference-between-mvcannotation-driven-and-contextannotation)